# Read REST API JSON reply

Tags: json, vb.net, api, json.net, rest-client

I have been searching the web back an forth but couldn't find a hint to my issue.

I'm calling a REST API via `RestSharp Client`. I retrieve a response like this:

```
{
 "meta": {
  "query_time": 0.007360045,
  "pagination": {
   "offset": 1,
   "limit": 100,
   "total": 1
  },
  "powered_by": "device-api",
  "trace_id": "a0d33897-5f6e-4799-bda9-c7a9b5368db7"
 },
 "resources": [
  "1363bd6422274abe84826dabf20cb6cd"
 ],
 "errors": []
}
```

I want to query the value of `resources` at the moment. This is the code I use:

```
Dim id_request = New RestRequest("/devices/queries/devices/v1?filter=" + filter, Method.GET)
id_request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json")
id_request.AddHeader("Authorization", "bearer " + bearer)
Dim data_response = data_client.Execute(id_request)
Dim data_response_raw As String = data_response.Content
Dim raw_id As JObject = JObject.Parse(data_response_raw)
Dim id = raw_id.GetValue("resources").ToString
```

Unfortunately, I'm only getting `["1363bd6422274abe84826dabf20cb6cd"]` as a reply instead of `1363bd6422274abe84826dabf20cb6cd`

Can anyone point me into the right direction?

I have also tried to deserialize using `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` but I somehow fail.

I found this solution here but if I try to rebuild it fails as it doesn't recognize the Dictionary part

```
 Dim tokenJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tokenJsonString)
 Dim jsonResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object))(jsonString)
 Dim firstItem = jsonResult.Item("data").Item(0)
```

EDIT:

When trying to deserialize the root as suggested but seems as if the 2nd response is nested JSON.

I have a reply like:

```
dr = {
     "meta": {
      "query_time": 0.004813129,
      "powered_by": "device-api",
      "trace_id": "5a355c86-37f7-416d-96c4-0c8796c940fc"
     },
     "resources": [
      {
       "device_id": "1363bd6422274abe84826dabf20cb6cd",
       "policies": [
        {
         "policy_type": "prevention",
         "policy_id": "1d34205a4e2c4d1991431c037c8e5734",
         "applied": true,
         "settings_hash": "7cb00a74",
         "assigned_date": "2021-02-22T13:56:37.759459481Z",
         "applied_date": "2021-02-22T13:57:19.962692301Z",
         "rule_groups": []
        }
       ],
       "meta": {
        "version": "352"
       }
      }
     ],
     "errors": []
    }
```

and I tried:

```
Dim restApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RestApiResponseRoot)(dr)
' This is your array of strings
Dim resources = restApiResponse.Resources
```

Unfortunately I get
**Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'resources', line 8, position 3.'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources Property is an array. As usual, you need to specify which element of the array you want to consider. In this case, the first one, i.e., the element at index `0`.

```
Dim jsonObject = JObject.Parse(data_response_raw)
Dim firstResource = jsonObject("resources")(0).ToString()
```

If you instead want the array content as a String array, not just the first element - assuming `resources` could contain more than one string (it's an array after all) -  deserialize to `String()`:

```
Dim jsonObject = JObject.Parse(data_response_raw)
Dim resources = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of String())(jsonObject("resources").ToString())
```

In case you need the whole JSON response, I suggest to deserialize to a class Model that represents the JSON:

```
Public Class RestApiResponseRoot
    Public Property Meta As Meta
    Public Property Resources As List(Of String)
    Public Property Errors As List(Of Object)
End Class
Public Class Meta
    <JsonProperty("query_time")>
    Public Property QueryTime As Double
    Public Property Pagination As Pagination
    <JsonProperty("powered_by")>
    Public Property PoweredBy As String
    <JsonProperty("trace_id")>
    Public Property TraceId As Guid
End Class
Public Class Pagination
    Public Property Offset As Long
    Public Property Limit As Long
    Public Property Total As Long
End Class
```

You can then deserialize the Model's Root object - the class named **`RestApiResponseRoot`** here - and access its Properties as usual:

```
Dim restApiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RestApiResponseRoot)(
    data_response_raw
)
' This is your array of strings
Dim resources = restApiResponse.Resources
```

The other JSON response is slightly different, the Response Property contains an array of objects instead of string.
Some more properties and nested object are added. You just need to adjust the Model.

```
Public Class RestApiResponseRoot2
    Public Property Meta As RootObjectMeta
    Public Property Resources As List(Of Resource)
    Public Property Errors As List(Of Object)
End Class

Public Class RootObjectMeta
    <JsonProperty("query_time")>
    Public Property QueryTime As Double
    <JsonProperty("powered_by")>
    Public Property PoweredBy As String
    <JsonProperty("trace_id")>
    Public Property TraceId As Guid
End Class

Public Class Resource
    <JsonProperty("device_id")>
    Public Property DeviceId As String
    Public Property Policies As List(Of Policy)
    Public Property Meta As ResourceMeta
End Class

Public Class ResourceMeta
    Public Property Version As String
End Class

Public Class Policy
    <JsonProperty("policy_type")>
    Public Property PolicyType As String
    <JsonProperty("policy_id")>
    Public Property PolicyId As String
    Public Property Applied As Boolean
    <JsonProperty("settings_hash")>
    Public Property SettingsHash As String
    <JsonProperty("assigned_date")>
    Public Property AssignedDate As DateTimeOffset
    <JsonProperty("applied_date")>
    Public Property AppliedDate As DateTimeOffset
    <JsonProperty("rule_groups")>
    Public Property RuleGroups As List(Of Object)
End Class
```

```
Dim restApiResponse2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RestApiResponseRoot2)(dr)
Dim resources As List(Of Resource) = restApiResponse2.Resources
' DeviceId of the first Resources object
Dim deviceId = resources(0).DeviceId
```

---

You can use some on-line resources to handle your JSON objects:

[JSON Formatter & Validator](http://jsonformatter)

[QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/) - JSON to .Net classes - C#, no VB.Net

[JSON Utils](https://jsonutils.com/) - JSON to .Net classes - includes VB.Net. Somewhat less *capable* than QuickType.

Comment: Hi Jimi, super thank you very much! I will analyze and get back :) Much appreciated!

Comment: Jimi, working almost like a charm :) I also tried to deserialize the root as suggested but seems as if the 2nd response is nested JSON

Comment: Hi Jimi, yes thank you very much already! I have updated the actual question with the 2nd response I get - seems as if the reply is getting complexer the more I query. Again thanks for you help!

Comment: Jimi this is a total awesome response! Think I got it now - very much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Try trimming the resources value with " character in first and last of the output